# How to setup SeoBundle and extract title?

Tags: php, symfony, seo

I Cant get SeoBundle to extract title from my picture

I have configured "content_key" in config.yml

```
cmf_seo:
    content_key: "mykey"
    title: "%%content_title%%"
```

My Entity implements TitleReadInterface

```
  class Picture implements TitleReadInterface {
  (...)

   public function getSeoTitle()
   {
      return $this->title;
   }

  (...)
}
```

And in controller i am updating the "mykey" attribute:

```
public function viewAction(Request $request, $slug) {
    (...)

    $picture =  $repository->findOneBySlug($slug);

    $request->attributes->set('mykey', $picture);

    (...)

}
```

Finally in view there is:

```
 {{ sonata_seo_title() }}
```

But page title is "Sonata Project" :( 
What is wrong?

Comment: really ? no one have an idea ?

Comment: It looks like Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\SeoBundle\EventListener\ContentListener::onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) is fired up before controller::viewAction and there is no 'mykey' attribute in request yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have figured out, that this bundle works better with DynamicRouter, if you don't use DynamicRouter (like in my case) you have to provide content object in another way. The solution for me was to trigger SeoPresentation process manually from controller:

```
public function viewAction(Request $request, $slug) {
  (...)

  $picture =  $repository->findOneBySlug($slug);

  $seo = $this->get('cmf_seo.presentation');
  $seo->updateSeoPage($picture);

  (...)

}
```